# Difference between Java widlcards and generics

Tags: java, generics, wildcard

what is the difference between these 2 method signatures?

1. `public <T> void fromArrayToList(List<?> a) { }`
2. `public <T> void fromArrayToList(List<T> a) { }`

One is taking a `List<T>`, and the other is taking a `List<?>`. I am able to pass a list containing objects of any type to both these methods without the compiler complaining.

Comment: In the first one (the `<T>` is obsolete), the type is unknown to you. In the second, you know the type and can name it, namely `T`. So the second would allow you to do `T foo = a.get(0)` and then `a.add(foo)`. The first cant do this, since you can not capture the type to put it back in (actually, you can with `var` or by just going raw-types...).

Comment: In general, you use wildcards if you truly dont care about the type. But use generics if you actually need to be able to name the type.